# Git installation failed

Tags: windows, git, github, version-control

I just installed Git on my Windows PC running Windows 8.1 keeping most of the options to the default.

Then I tried to check the version using

```
git --version
```

Got this error message

```
C:\Windows\system32>git --version
fatal: open /dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory
```

Git version - Git-2.27.0-64-bit
Source : https://gitforwindows.org/
What might went wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include some more details, e.g.: What version of git did you install? Where did you download it from? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+open+%2Fdev%2Fnull+or+dup+failed%3A+No+such+file+or+directory